# Continuously Consuming API in winform (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, api, webrequest

I've made a simple program that has to continuosly check for data based on API.
So far, what I've done is making a timer, then execute the GET procedures on timer event

```
private void TimerStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //stop timer
    TimerStatus.Stop();
    //get data
    getCommand();
    //restart timer
    TimerStatus.Start();
}

void getCommand()
{
    string url = "https://somewhere/getcommand?token=somekey&param=";
    string param = "0";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url + param ); ;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        
        bool connected = false;
        if ((((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription) == "OK")
            connected = true;

        //continue if connected
        if (connected)
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.  
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                
                //check output
                Console.WriteLine("Respond from server : " + responseFromServer);
                
                try
                {
                    //parse data, store value
                    parseThenProcess(responseFromServer);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //parsing data error
                    Console.WriteLine("exception error response");
                }
            }
        }
        // Close the response.  
        response.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get command failed");
    }
}
```

This code works fine for me. However, when I try to add more command that has different API in the timer event, the winforms feels kinda laggy. Is it just error on my side that irrelevant with the API handling or do I need to make some improvement about how to handle the API?

```
    private void TimerStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //stop timer
    TimerStatus.Stop();
    //get data
    getCommand_A();
    getCommand_B();
    getParameter_C();
    getParameter_D();
    //restart timer
    TimerStatus.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using a windows timer? And I am not joking. You have various approaches:

- Learn how to use async and the async web interfaces so you do not block the UI thread too long.

or

- use a separate thread or tasks (no need for a timer , you can have a task that then schedules another task, i.e.).

What you do is running it all on the UI thread and that is really not needed. Especially because you do send that synchronous so the UI blocks while the request is executed .This is a problem solved for many years by the UI knowing of async methods.

Comment: Thanks, I dont realize that the request execution will bock UI. Your first approach is understandable, bu can you elaborate more on your 2nd approach?

Comment: The winforms timer actually calls back into the UI thread. 2nd approach is just to use a task. Look up the task api. Or start a separate thread.

Comment: My bad, I thought you mean 'task' literally. I haven't look up much into Task<T>, but I assume its just making another thread that will do the task. If so, how can make it executing continously without having a timer?